# Coming from C++ to AS3 : what are fundamental AS3 data structures classes?

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, data-structures

We are porting out game from C++ to web; the game make extensive use of STL.

Can you provide short comparison chart (and if possible, a bit of code samples for basic operations like insertion/deletion/searching and (where applicable) equal_range/binary_search) for the classes what are equivalents to the following STL containers :

```
std::vector
std::set
std::map
std::list
stdext::hash_map
```

?

Thanks a lot for your time!

**UPD:**
wow, it seems we do not have everything we needhere :(

Can anyone point to some industry standard algorithms library for AS3 programs (like boost in C++)?
I can not believe people can write non-trivial software without balanced binary search trees (std::set std::map)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The choices of data structures are significantly more limited in as3. You have:

- [`Array`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) or [`Vector.<*>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) which stores a list of values and can be added to after construction
- [`Dictionary`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) (hash_map) which stores key/value pairs

maps and sets aren't really supported as there's no way to override object equality. As for binary search, most search operations take a predicate function for you to override equality for that search.

**Edit:** As far as common algorithm and utility libraries, I'd take a look at [as3commons](http://www.as3commons.org/)

Comment: A `Dictionary` is essentially an `std::hash_map`, rather than `std::map` because `std::map` keeps the keys sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [library](https://github.com/polygonal/ds) will fit your needs.